# CSS: How to force background image to stretch/compress to fit div, without keeping aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I'm having a frustrating issue, and would love some help.

I've written a script to allow me to resize a div on screen for an application I'm building for a client, but I've run into a humorous issue I've not had before. I know plenty of ways to make sure that an image ***Does*** keep its aspect ratio, but I'm not sure of how to force one not to. If, for example, the div is 200px tall and 20px wide, I want it to deform the image to fit that box.

For the application I'm building, this particular image needs to compress/stretch to fit the parent div, regardless of aspect ratio. At the point I'm at right now, I can do this as an image inside of a div tag, or as a background image to the div.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would love to hear them.

Comment: Sorry, what's the problem? You've said you can use `background` or `img` so why not?

Comment: "I know plenty of ways to make sure that an image Does keep its aspect ratio, but I'm not sure of how to force one not to. If, for example, the div is 200px tall and 20px wide, I want it to deform the image to fit that box."

Comment: Could you post any relevant code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `background-size: 100% 100%` for this:

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: url(https://unsplash.it/100x100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Yep, this is what I needed. Bizarre, considering I tried using Background-size like that before and it didn't work correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a re-sizeable example using `background`:

```css
div{
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/200/300)no-repeat 0 0;
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here's another using `img`:

```css
div{
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:300px;
  width:200px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If anyone else notices the missing resize graphic in the second example and has (or wants to know) the solution, I've asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46979879/how-can-i-bring-the-css-resize-icon-above-a-child-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, the background-size property can transform the way the background image proportions itself to the element.

```
background-size: cover
```

Edit:

If you want to keep the  structure, you can use CSS object-fit properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: I've tried cover, but it's still maintaining the aspect ratio when the div gets smaller than the original image, and simply hiding the overflow.

I need the image to strech or compress itself so that the entire image is always visible, completely forgetting the aspect ratio.

Comment: Have you looked at the object-fit property?