# How can I bring the CSS resize icon above a child img tag?

Tags: html, css

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46979343/4907552) to another question I noticed the CSS `resize` handle icon of a parent `div` can be obfuscated by an `img`. In that answer it doesn't really matter, as `background` is more appropriate anyway and could be used instead.

However, let's say (for some bizarre reason) you wanted an `img` inside a resizeable `div`, how could you bring the icon above it?

I wasn't sure if it was just an optical illusion of some kind, so I used a colour wheel with a white centre to test it:

```css
div{
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/RGB_color_wheel_72.svg"/>
</div>
```

Here is a browser comparison:

[image: Browser comparison]

Edge and IE [don't support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize) CSS `resize` so they couldn't be tested. I believe Opera uses the same Engine as Chrome so it's no surprise they both failed. However, it works as you would expect in Firefox. Is there a fix for Blink?

Comment: That's actually very weird... Thought about the `::-webkit-resizer` pseudo, but as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5kdr/) shows, it only applies to `textarea` elements, not to regular elements with the `resize` property. Also there seems to be a strange bug, where all of the changes made to a `::webkit-resizer` pseudo only applies when the `textarea` reaches a specific height

Comment: Given the examples and tests (And considering cross browser implementations, if this is even a concern, since FF doesn't seem to have this bug), the only way to have the icon in front of a child `img` is use JS or [apply `position: relative` and `z-index: -1` to the `img`](http://jsfiddle.net/vu0gfwb4/) (Didn't want to turn this into an answer since it seems too monkeypatchey to me)

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz Wow, how bizarre. It is not exactly an ideal solution but it is one nonetheless - I would add it as an answer just so everyone knows it's been thought of already :)

Comment: yeah, you're right, it'll be good for anyone that might face this problem, will do it in a minute

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought about the `::-webkit-resizer` pseudo element, but upon further testing, I found out that it only considers `textarea` elements, not other elements that uses the `resize` property. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q5kdr/) showing this behavior.

Also, notice that even on the `textarea` element, `::-webkit-resizer` style changes only kick in after it reaches a certain height (Very very small). This is also reproducible through the fiddle above.

Given that, it seems to me that the best alternative to "fix" this bug is to use [a custom JS resizer lib](https://github.com/anhr/resizer).

A (rather monkeypatchey) pure css workaround is to apply a negative `z-index` to the child `img`

```css
div{
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:400px;
  width:400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/32/RGB_color_wheel_72.svg"/>
</div>
```